# Cash Register Free Code Camp algorithm Help Needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help with my code for the Cash Register Challenge on FreeCodeCamp. I am passing other checks except the ones for "OPEN"

For the second check, I get the correct breakdown ["QUARTER":0.25], ["QUARTER":0.25] i.e. two quarters but I don't know how to add this together and return it as ["QUARTER":0.5].

For the third, the breakdown is nearly there but its not taking away the final penny so I am missing one ["PENNY":0.01] from the final breakdown. When I check the change remaining, its one penny.

So what I really need help with is returning the change as a combined value for each type of unit and see why its not returning the total amount on the third case.

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var cashAvailable = cid;
  var units = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
  ].reverse()
  var cashAvailable = cid.slice().reverse()
  var stat = {
    status: '',
    change: []
  };
  var changeRequired = cash - price;
  var totalCash = cashAvailable.flat().filter(x => {
    return isNaN(x) == false
  }).reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }).toFixed(2)
  var unitsNeeded = []
  if (totalCash == changeRequired) {
    stat.status = 'CLOSED'
    stat.change = cid
  } else if (totalCash < changeRequired) {
    stat.status = 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS'
    stat.change = []
  } else if (totalCash > changeRequired) {
    for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
      while (changeRequired >= units[i][1] && cashAvailable[i][1] > 0) {
        unitsNeeded.push(units[i])
        cashAvailable[i][1] -= units[i][1]
        console.log((changeRequired -= units[i][1]).toFixed(2))
      }
      if (changeRequired > units[8][1]) {
        stat.status = 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS'
        stat.change = []
      } else {
        stat.status = 'OPEN';
        stat.change = unitsNeeded
      }
    }
  }

  return stat
}

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
])

checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
])
```

these are the two checks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, but hints that can help to find a solution:

Here you assign a text (not a number) to `var totalCash`. `toFixed()` is a number formatting function returning a string for good reasons: Number like `0.01` do not exists due the binary based implementation of floats. Don't use it for rounding numbers, it will not work!

```
  var totalCash = cashAvailable.flat().filter(x => {
    return isNaN(x) == false
  }).reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }).toFixed(2)
```

And then you do numerical comparisons with the text:

```
  if (totalCash == changeRequired) {
      ...
  } else if (totalCash < changeRequired) {
      ...
  } else if (totalCash > changeRequired) {
      ...
  }
```

**Solution:** Remove `toFixed(2)` from above and use generally `toFixed()` only for visualization!

**Another hint:**
Here you modify the value of `changeRequired` as part of a `console.log()` statement. If you later remove the log, the semantics of the code will change:

```
console.log((changeRequired -= units[i][1]).toFixed(2))
```

Better:

```
changeRequired -= units[i][1];
console.log(changeRequired.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demo uses a class and ES6 Map. Details commented in demo.

```js
/* This Map represents what the till has initially. Each value is 
the count of each type -- not the monetary value.*/
let funds = new Map([
  ['One Hundred', 2],
  ['Twenty', 10],
  ['Ten', 20],
  ['Five', 20],
  ['One', 50],
  ['Quarter', 20],
  ['Dime', 25],
  ['Nickel', 30],
  ['Penny', 100]
]);

/** Register(funds)
@Params: funds[Map]: key = name / value = count not monetary
A class that has the following methods:
  - set/get change 
      Allows direct access to this._change constructor property.
  - transact(cost, payment)
      Simply subtracts cost from payment to determine amount of
      change.
  - distribute(title = 'Change') 
      Takes a given amount and distributes it as currency in the
      smallest amount of denominations. If a title isn't passed, 
      the default is used.
  - remaining(map, title = 'Remaining in Till')
      Pass the Map of change and return a Map of remaining money
      from the fund Map. If a title isn't passed, the default is
      used.
  - displayMap(map)
      A utility method to aid in displaying Maps.
*/
class Register {
  constructor(funds) {
    this.denomination = new Map([
      ["One Hundred", 100],
      ["Twenty", 20],
      ["Ten", 10],
      ["Five", 5],
      ["One", 1],
      ["Quarter", 0.25],
      ["Dime", 0.1],
      ["Nickel", 0.05],
      ["Penny", 0.01]
    ]);
    this.distribution = funds;
    this._change = 0.00;
  }

  set change(money) {
    this._change = money;
  }

  get change() {
    return this._change;
  }

  transact(cost, payment) {
    this.change = payment - cost;
    return this.change;
  }

  distribute(title = 'Change') {
    let dist = new Map();
    dist.set('||', `~~~~~~~~~~[${title}]~~~~~~~~~~`);
    let total = Number(this.change);
    let denom = Array.from(this.denomination.entries());

    for (let [key, value] of denom) {
      if (total >= value) {
        let money = Math.floor(total / value);
        dist.set(key, money);
        total = total % value;
      }
    }
    return dist;
  }

  remaining(map, title = 'Remaining in Till') {
    for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
      if (this.distribution.has(key)) {
        let fund = this.distribution.get(key);
        this.distribution.set(key, (fund - value));
      }
    }
    map.set('|', `~~~~~~~~~~[${title}]~~~~~~~~~~`);
    return this.distribution;
  }

  displayMap(map) {
    for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
      console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    }
  }
}

// Instantiate class instance as `r` pass the funds Map
const r = new Register(funds);

// Arbitrary values
let cost = 252.63;
let payment = 300.00;

// set/get this.change from constructor
r.transact(cost, payment);

// Returns the change in the least amount of denominations
const dist = r.distribute();

// Returns the remaining count of each denomination after change
const till = r.remaining(dist);

// Display Maps
r.displayMap(dist);
r.displayMap(till);
```